# Casting a tr1::function to a void*

Tags: c++

I have the following tr1::function prototype that I am trying to cast to a void*:

```
typedef std::tr1::function<cv::Mat (const cv::Mat,const void*)> preprocessingFunc;
```

In this function I am storing it in a vector that contains structures denoting the type of function and the pointer to the function:

```
void ImageGraph::addNode(preprocessingFunc func)
{
    NodeFunction nodeFunction = { typeid(func), (void*)func };
    //nodes.push_back(nodeFunction);
}
```

The error I get:

> ImagePipeline.cpp: In member function ‘void IP::ImageGraph::addNode(IP::preprocessingFunc)’:
>   ImagePipeline.cpp:32: error: invalid cast from type ‘IP::preprocessingFunc’ to type ‘void*’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/typeinfo:135: error: ‘std::type_info::type_info(const std::type_info&)’ is private
>   ImagePipeline.cpp:32: error: within this context

Is it possible to cast this function type to a pointer (void*)? If not, is there a better way to achieve what I am doing?

For clarity I am storing function pointers to call at later dates, and their are currently 3 types of function pointers, however I would like to store them all in the same vector.

Comment: No. `tr1::function` is a class, not a function pointer. The object `func` cannot be turned into a `void*`.

Comment: @BoPersson: I don't follow; `void*` can hold pointers to any object including a `tr1::function` object. Mixing code and data pointers would have been troublesome, but `std::function` as you correctly indicate is not a function pointer. (It _has_ one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to a member function can not be stored in a function pointer, because, essentially, a member function has a hidden argument (the "this" pointer).

There are two solutions: Either a real "pointer to member function" (which requires the correct type of function pointer), or make the function static, and pass in the object itself as a pointer (e.g. a void).

To me, this seems like kind of an odd solution, and I would think there are better solutions, such as using an interface class, and add your interface objects as "nodes", perhaps?

For a bit more on "pointer to member function", have a look here:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html

But given the comment below, you are actually trying to store an object in a pointer. That's similar to `(void *)3.1415926;` - it doesn't make sense. You probably shouldn't use void * here, but something else, such as pointer to function<> [and change your addNode to take a pointer to a preprocessingFunc object].

Comment: Sorry, the whole answer is correct but does not appear applicable. `IP::preprocessingFunc` does not denote a pointer to member function, but is a typedef in the scope `IP`.

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching it from the wrong end, it seems. Why are you using `void*` ? You state that you have " currently 3 types of function pointers". To store callable things, use `tr1::function<>`. It can be initialized from most reasonable sources: function pointers, bound pointers to member functions, functors, and obviously other `tr1::function`s